# Fields in a Block of a Step disappears while designing an Omniscripts

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, omnis-studio-8

I'm working on a **Omni Scripts (Vlocity)**. I'm designing a screen flow where I have Asset Mgmt Quote, Tax, Doc Request, Sales, Pricing etc., screens. These screens are set by the record Id of the corresponding object. When we select any one screen we will get navigate to respective screen. Each screens contains different fields either prepopulated with some values or user can enter a value. Each screen designed with respective input as Step -> Block -> Fields. These steps can have any number of blocks and each blocks can have any no. of fields based on the requirements.

While designing, like while adding the **Fields** inside a **Block.** I faced an issue like the **Fields** get disappeared after adding in the **Blocks**. The Blocks are still visible but the fields inside are disappearing.

This issue comes when designing, While I **Activate** the version , I could see the fields in those Blocks. And During **Preview** phase also I could see the fields in the each blocks of the screen. **This issue arises only when Designing**.
I found it difficult to enter the details of the each fields when this issue remains. Is there any solution for this issue or any idea about why this issues arises??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Vlocity is closer to config than code so your question is poor fit for stackoverflow. Try asking on dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/, more admins over there?